# Double symlink of vim doesnt load library file ncurses.so.6 when invoked with sudo

Tags: sudo, vim, symlink, ldconfig

I have a symlink of the vim.basic executable:

```
⤷ ls -l /etc/alternatives/vim
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 18 Apr 22 21:02 /etc/alternatives/vim -> /usr/bin/vim.basic
```

Another symlink to the above symlink as:

```
⤷ ls -l /usr/bin/vim         
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 21 Apr 22 21:02 /usr/bin/vim -> /etc/alternatives/vim
```

They are system configured as I would expect from update-alternatives and I haven't changed anything except I boot sometimes from linux kernel 5.4 or generally from 4.15 using the same root and home partition and this probably what created a problem running vim with sudo?:

```
⤷ sudo vim.basic                #This works fine!
⤷ sudo /etc/alternatives/vim    #This works fine!
⤷ sudo vim      
vim: error while loading shared libraries: libncurses.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

libncurses.so is installed in a path pointed to by LD_LIBRARY_PATH:

```
⤷ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/home/akd/dotapps/local/lib:

⤷ ls -l /home/akd/dotapps/local/lib/libncurses.so.6
lrwxrwxrwx 1 akd akd 17 Nov  9 21:24 /home/akd/dotapps/local/lib/libncurses.so.6 -> libncurses.so.6.2
```

I can't seem to understand why the double symlink cannot find the libcurses.so.6 on sudo vim operation. Normal vim binary without sudo works as expected though (doesnt compain about ncurses lib).

```
⤷ vim --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.2 (2019 Dec 12, compiled Feb 16 2021 13:33:23)
⤷ sudo --version
Sudo version 1.8.21p2
Sudoers policy plugin version 1.8.21p2
Sudoers file grammar version 46
Sudoers I/O plugin version 1.8.21p2
```

Any idea, why this weird behavior?

Update:

Adding more info as req:

```
⤷ ldd $(which vim)        
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffc9a2a6000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f9d5e059000)
    libncurses.so.6 => /home/akd/dotapps/local/lib/libncurses.so.6 (0x00007f9d5ddee000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f9d5dbea000)
    libpython3.6m.so.1.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0 (0x00007f9d5d53f000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f9d5d320000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f9d5cf2f000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f9d5e909000)
    libexpat.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1 (0x00007f9d5ccfd000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f9d5cae0000)
    libutil.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libutil.so.1 (0x00007f9d5c8dd000)
```

Comment: `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is probably only set for user `akd`.  When you `sudo`, you run as a different user and the environment is pretty clean.  Try `sudo -E vim`.  `-E` will preserve your environment including `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Comment: Nope, no luck, same error.

Comment: Just updated the footer with this info.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have installed `libncurses.so` in `akb`'s home directory, and made it available by adding `export ENVIRONMENT=/home/akb/.../lib` to `/home/akb/.bashrc`.

This is all user-specific.  If you were to run this as another user (`sudo -u akc vim`), you'd run into the problem where user `akc` doesn't have read-permissions in `/home/akb` so `akc` can't read the library.  The environment is also refreshed, so anything you `export` in `/home/akb/.bashrc` is not applied.

To solve this you'll want to install `libncurses.so` system-wide.  The recommended option is to use the version supplied with your distribution (example):

```
sudo apt install libncurses6
```

But you have a local copy, and I assume that's for a reason.  In that case you'll want to install it system-wide with:

```
./configure
make
sudo make install DESTDIR=/usr/local
```

I *am* a little curious about your release of `vim`.  `vim.basic` 8.2 on debian does not depend on `ncurses`.  If you've built/installed from sources, then it sounds very plausible that you are missing this runtime dependency.  But if you installed via package, then I would expect your package manager to automatically install all configured runtime dependencies.  Therefore it sounds like bad flags passed to `./configure` when the package was built, or missing `Depends:` which you should inform the package maintainer about.

Comment: That last comment is questionable: vim (non-GUI) is a *termcap* application as such, and that interface is provided on all Debian releases by *ncurses* (`libtinfo` is part of ncurses).

Comment: Hey, thank you! I could validate it since sudo su root env didnt work with simple vim. I installed it system-wide.

Comment: But the actual doubt being that why double symlink doesn't work with sudo, while the single symlinks work as expected, is still now clear to me! So leaving the question un-answered for now.